# About duplication IP Settings on Cisco L3 Switch

Tags: networking, cisco, ip

I set up the IP for Cisco L3 switch, but why is the error only eth 1/2 even though there is an IP duplication as shown below?

```
SW(config)#
SW(config)# interface mgmt 0
SW(config-if)# ip address 192.168.1.1/24
SW(config-if)# no shutdown
SW(config-if)# exit
SW(config)#
SW(config)#
SW(config)# interface vlan 10
SW(config-if)# ip address 192.168.1.1/24
SW(config-if)# exit
SW(config)#
SW(config)#
SW(config)# int ethernet 1/1
SW(config-if)# no switchport
SW(config-if)# ip address 192.168.1.1/24
SW(config-if)# no shut
SW(config-if)#
SW(config-if)#
SW(config-if)# int ethernet 1/2
SW(config-if)# 
SW(config-if)# no switchport
SW(config-if)# ip address 192.168.1.1/24
% 192.168.1.1/24 overlaps with address configured on Ethernet1/1
SW(config-if)#
```

Comment: what is a product model??

Comment: >what is a product model?? 　→　It's Nexus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a Nexus switch.

1. The management port is in a separate VRF by default.  So duplication is allowed.
2. The Vlan interface is shutdown, so addresses aren't checked.
3. You've enabled Eth 1/1, so the switch starts checking other addresses you enter against it.

Comment: This is very answer, 1 ! thank you.